# How to add a column to Pandas based off of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas and I have a very basic dataframe:

```
                   session_id              datetime
5  t0ubmqqpbt01rhce201cujjtm7  2014-11-28T04:30:09Z
6  k87akpjpl004nbmhf4loiafi72  2014-11-28T04:30:11Z
7  g0t7hrqo8hgc5vlb7240d1n9l5  2014-11-28T04:30:12Z
8  ugh3fkskmedq3br99d20t78gb2  2014-11-28T04:30:15Z
9  fckkf16ahoe1uf9998eou1plc2  2014-11-28T04:30:18Z
```

I wish to add a third column based on the values of the current columns:

```
df['key'] = urlsafe_b64encode(md5('l' + df['session_id'] + df['datetime']))
```

But I receive:

> TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not Series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). The code below will apply the lambda function to each row of `df`. You could, of course, define a separate function (if you need to do more something more complicated).

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from base64  import urlsafe_b64encode
from hashlib import md5

s = '''                   session_id              datetime
5  t0ubmqqpbt01rhce201cujjtm7  2014-11-28T04:30:09Z
6  k87akpjpl004nbmhf4loiafi72  2014-11-28T04:30:11Z
7  g0t7hrqo8hgc5vlb7240d1n9l5  2014-11-28T04:30:12Z
8  ugh3fkskmedq3br99d20t78gb2  2014-11-28T04:30:15Z
9  fckkf16ahoe1uf9998eou1plc2  2014-11-28T04:30:18Z'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep='\s+')

df['key'] = df.apply(lambda x: urlsafe_b64encode(md5('l' + x['session_id'] + x['datetime'])), axis=1)
```

*Note: I couldn't get the hashing bit working on my machine unfortunately, some unicode error (might be because I'm using Python 3) and I don't have time to debug the inner workings of it, but the pandas part I'm pretty sure about :P*

Comment: I'm also stuck with the unicode, but that is the proper function, thanks